# The sequence without using loops

Tags: python

The sequence is given ("1", "2", ... "n"). I need to get from it a string like "{1 {2 {.. {n}
..}}}" without using loops. I can do it with loops, but dont have an idea how to do it without loop. Maybe I can do it using `if... else...` or there any libraries?

input:

```
 ("1", "2", ... "n")
```

output:

```
{1 {2 {.. {n}..}}}
```

With loop:

```
for i in ints:
    print('item {{} = {}'.format(???, i))
```

Comment: What is bad on loops? Also please define what exactly does "without using loops" mean. The answers with `join` does not use loops in Python code, but surely there are some loops in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it (I called your input `a`):

```
'{ ' + '{ '.join(a) + '}'*len(a)
```

```
'{ 1{ 2{ 3{ n}}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
items = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
print('{' + '{'.join(items) + '}'  * len(items))
```

Output

```
{1{2{3{4}}}}
```

Comment: This is not at all different than my answer except for the fact that it doesn't replicate OP's desired output

Answer (score -2):

```
n = int(input())
a = map(str, range(1, n+1))
'{ '+'{ '.join(a)+'}'*n
```